# ¿Como puedo utilizar un único js para un sito web (múltiples documentos html)?

Tags: javascript, html, elementos

Estoy tratando de usar un único archivo js para un sitio web pero al obtener algún elemento y agregarle un evento me marca el error

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Este código es de ejemplo pero muestra el problema que tengo

Index.html:

```
<body>
    <h1>pagina de inicio</h1>
    <button id="button1">boton 1</button>
    <br />
    <a href="segunda_pagina.html">segunda pagina</a>
    
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Segunda_pagina.html:

```
<body>
    <h1>segunda pagina</h1>
    <button id="button2">boton 2</button>
    <br />
    <a href="index.html">inicio</a>
    
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Index.js:

```
const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');

const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

button1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    alert('click en boton 1')
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    alert('click en boton 2')
})
```

El problema que tengo es que trato de obtener  a dos botones que están en distintos html's entonces, al estar en el index me da error en el addEventListener del button2, y cuando estoy en la segunda_pagina me da el error en el addEventListener del button1, ¿como puedo obtener esos botones sin que me dé el error pero usando un único js para todo el sitio?, o ¿es imposible hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste lo siguiente:

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Incluir tu código dentro del (document) ready.
Quizás por eso tu error.

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas analizar si el botón existe: [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) devuelve el elemento (si existe) o `null` (si no existe).

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

// Solo si existe el botón 1
if(button1) {
    button1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        alert('Click en botón 1');
    });
}

// Solo si existe el botón 2
if(button2) {
    button2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        alert('Clic en botón 2');
    });
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Botón 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es cuestión de usar un condicional que verifique el elemento HTML.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let btn_1 = null
  let btn_2 = null
  if (document.getElementById("button_1")) {
    console.log("Existe boton 1")
    btn_1 = document.getElementById("button_1")
    //... agregas el evento
  }
  if (document.getElementById("button_2")) {
    console.log("Existe boton 2")
    btn_2 = document.getElementById("button_2")
    //... agregas el evento
  }
  
  
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button_1">Click Me!</button>
```